# Prometheus postgresql node_exporter configuration

Tags: postgresql, prometheus

I want to start monitoring my postgreSQL servers via Prometheus.  Prometheus is up and running.

Prometheus.yml:

```
- job_name: 'postgres-exporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['sql01:9187']
```

Found this postgresql node exporter: https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter

How do I need to install this exporter? The github readme is talking about building it via Mage?

I have downloaded the following file via releases: https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter/releases/download/v0.4.7/postgres_exporter_v0.4.7_linux-386.tar.gz on my postgresql server.

How to continue from here? Do I need to install Go first?

I've configured the env var:

```
export DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://<adminuser>:<adminpw>@hostname:5432/test_db"
```

Appreciate any help!

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not run it with the provided Docker container?

From their README.md:

```
docker run --net=host -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
```

To answer your question, yes you will need to install Go to build that project. You could skip installing Go by running the docker image instead.

---

Edit: Just realized you downloaded the release.

It's as simple as unzipping the tarball: `tar -xvf postgres_exporter_v0.4.7_linux-386.tar.gz` and running it (`./path/to/postgres_exporter`, assuming you have the environment variables set.